# List comprehension - use each element twice

Tags: python

I have two lists as follows:

```
first = [1, 2, 3] # integers
second = ["A", "B"]
```

I want to produce the following list, with alternating A and B. Notice that the resulting iterable is longer than the input iterables:

```
["1A", "1B", "2A", "2B", "3A", "3B"]
```

I am currently using `itertools`:

```
[str(x1) + x2 for x1, x2 in itertools.product(first, second)]
```

But is this the "nicest" way? Is there a solution which doesn't require an import?

Comment: `itertools.product` is a native tool

Comment: `itertools.product` is a native function. If by that you mean built-in the answer is just a nested loop but there's no specific function for that task.

Comment: Why do you think `itertools` is not a "native" solution?

Comment: @DeepSpace I think I meant "a solution which doesn't require an import". That's what I think of as native. I'm willing to have my vocabulary updated here!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid an import? This seems like a very arbitrary constraint? You should use `itertools` IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try

```
>>> first = [1, 2, 3]
>>> second = ['A', 'B']
>>> ["{}{}".format(f, s) for s in second for f in first]
['1A', '2A', '3A', '1B', '2B', '3B']
```

Comment: I'd use `itertools.product` just for the sake of scalability: `print(["{}{}".format(f, s) for f, s in product(first, second)])`

Comment: @DeepSpace But the question is, if I got it right, to find an alternative to `itertools.product`.

Comment: Small change to get the elements in the same order as given in the question: `["{}{}".format(f, s) for f in first for s in second]`

Answer (score 2):

The best way is using a nested loop or use `itertools.product()` but if you want a functional approach you can use `itertools.starmap`, `operator.add` and some built-in functions such as `map()` and `list()` as following:

```
>>> from itertools import product, starmap
>>> from operator import add
>>> 
>>> list(starmap(add, product(map(str, first), second)))
['1A', '1B', '2A', '2B', '3A', '3B']
```

Comment: "Is there a solution which doesn't require an import?" (arbitrary I know)- your solution is to use multiple imports instead?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I missed the edit, at first if was native solution. But I'll still leave it for the sake of educational purposes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the alternative to `itertools.product`, check [Arount's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45009627/7051394).

About the string formatting now, it's not very Pythonic (and not scalable at all) to use `str(x) + y`.
Instead, use the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) string method, or even better, Python 3.6's [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#specification):

```
>>> "{}{}".format(x, y)
>>> "{firstValue}{secondValue}".format(firstValue=x, secondValue=y)
>>> f"{x}{y}"
```

Here is a link to the [string formatting documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).